# Lagrangian subspaces are graphs of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$, which is the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with symmetric bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ given by
$$\langle e_{i},e_{j}\rangle=\pm\delta_{i,j},$$ 
with a $+$ sign when $i=j\leq n$ and a $-$ sign when $i=j>n$.

A subspace $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is called Lagrangian when $E=E^{\perp}$ (orthogonal for $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$).

For a matrix $A\in GL(n)$ we consider $E_{A}=\{(Av,v):v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. It is not too hard to see that $E_{A}$ is Lagrangian iff. $A\in O(n)$.

However, I read that every Lagrangian subspace $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is of the form $E_{A}$ for unique $A\in O(n)$. Does somebody know a proof for this fact, or a reference for a proof? Thanks.

Comment: The set $\{(Av,v):v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\}$ (as you've written it) is a set of real numbers, not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$.  Could you mean $\{v \in \Bbb R^n: (Av,v) = 0\}$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: By $(\cdot,\cdot)$ I mean a pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The bilinear form is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.